# How to select 2 elements in a particular order from same column comparing them with another attribute?

Tags: sql

I have a table of name and salaries.
I want an output like a person's name followed by another person's name who has more salary than the previous one in a row.

if a table like this is there.

```
     Name   Salary
      Raj    10000
      Karan  15000
      Tarun  11000
```

Expected output should be like

```
    Raj Karan
    Raj Tarun
    Tarun Karan
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT 
  t1.Name,
  t2.Name
FROM tablename t1
INNER JOIN tablename t2
  ON t2.Salary > t1.Salary
```

Comment: No, the names are in a same column of same table.

Comment: @rahulvenkat It's self join, you could read more at here http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-self-join/

Comment: oh wait yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using self join

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b553ca8726523883dadecb6ebbf8e658)**

```
select a.name,b.name from t1 a 
inner join t1 b on a.salary<b.salary
```

OUTPUT:

```
name    name
Raj     Karan
Tarun   Karan
Raj     Tarun
```